# Can't call onActivityResult after the setting result in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have Activity_1 with Fragment_1. And in Fragment_1 I start new Activity_2 with nested Fragment_2_1 and Fragment_2_2:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(a, Constants.REQUESTCODE_REJECT_PROPOSAL);
```

The `onActivityResult` method is overriding in Activity_1 and Fragment_1:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TAG + "Got Result " + String.valueOf(resultCode),     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TAG + "Got Result " + String.valueOf(resultCode),     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode==Constants.REQUESTCODE_REJECT_PROPOSAL)
        {
            Log.i(TAG + " onActivityResult", " REQUESTCODE_REJECT_PROPOSAL");
            getMyProposals();
        }
    }
}
```

When Activity_2 started, the Fragment_2_1 is displaying. With the button click I replace Fragment_2_1 with Fragment 2_2. And I finish the Activity_2 in Fragment_2_2 by button clicking:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

But somehow  `onActivityResult` not being called neither in Fragment_1 and Activity_1. What can

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Reason was in setting

```
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

for the Activity_1 in AndroidManifest.

Removing that property solved my issue.